# How to uninstall during installation in insall shield

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

How to uninstall during installation in insall shield

i have built a Merge module using installshield 2010 . 
i have a built a main install shield using the same version.

i have included that merge module in the main installer
For some reasons i have to uninstall the whole product and install the product again during installation .
when i double click the .msi(setup) file . it has to uninstall the product first and then install new feature which i have added in the installer

Please can someone help me??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look at a major upgrade - they do exactly that, uninstall the older product as the new one is installed. I don't know how you specify that in the InstallShield IDE, but major upgrade, the upgrade table, RemoveExistingProducts are things to look for.

Comment: Can you be more specific please.. bcz i am new to installer

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not an InstallShield guy, so I don't know how the InstallShield IDE lets you specify that you want a major upgrade. If you can't follow the docs like this link, you could try the InstallShield community. I found these in a 1 minute search http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/MajorUpgrade.htm http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x666kd_how-to-create-a-major-upgrade-with_news